# Different name, same method - one runs, the other not

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have two methods in C# behind code and in the html have a ajax function, when my button is clicked, trigger the function and goes to the method, into de ajax when the URL is `"Reservas.aspx/paginacion",` its OK but when the URL is `"Reservas.aspx/delMethod",` it doesn't work, but it's the same, I only changed the name

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getId(clickid) {
            alert(clickid);
            NextPage(clickid);
        };
        function NextPage(clicka) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Reservas.aspx/paginacion",
                data: '{id: "' + clicka + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response);
            //$('#'+a).attr("class","active");           
        }    
    </script>
```

and the methods

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void delMethod(string id)
    {
        var myId = id;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void paginacion(string id)
    {
        var myId = id;

    }
```

when write delMethod into Ajax URL, the method doesn't run, but when write paginacion into Ajax URL, the method runs very well

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: when write delMethod into Ajax URL, the method doesn't run, but when write paginacion into Ajax URL, the method run very well

Comment: Any errors in the browser console or network tab? Maybe you have some routing rules set up that are conflicting... it's difficult to try and guess the problem from just the information you have provided

Comment: this is also easier to read:`JSON.stringify({id: clicka}),`

Comment: if they are in same page, same parameter and same ajax call and only the function name is different they suppose to work fine, unless you have routing or other configuration issue

Comment: Can you add an OnFail function in javascript just like you have the OnSuccess and paste the error here if there is any?

Comment: ok, just Add `function OnFail(response) {  alert(response);  }` and the result is `[object Object]` but doesn't go through the method (thx for edit my question)

Comment: Spelling error? since its ``pagination`` (``t`` instead of ``c``)

Comment: @RandRandom this method runs, but the other method with the same structure does'n work, I'm trying add alerts in the code and search where is the problem

Comment: Can you try function OnFail(JSON.stringify(response))

Comment: yes, get it, `Web method unknown work. Parameter name: methodName    [ArgumentException: web method work unknow.\r\nParameter name: methodName]\r\n   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetMethodData(String methodName) +178\r\n   System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +225\r\n   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +200\r\n   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +70\r\n`

Comment: Try removing the static keywords from delMethod and paginacion

Comment: It's weird, a workmate says me, copy the method that works and change the name, and this run ok... but it doesn't make sense, I can work with this solution but it's very strange, thx for all, for u comments, If I can run a new method, I'll make you know, and if someone discovers what happens, I would really appreciate it if you tell me